# Is it possible to iterate the application of a non-endomorphism?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

In Haskell if I want to repeatedly apply an endomorphism `a -> a` to a value of type `a` I can just use `iterate`.

What about a function that is not an endomorphisms, but generic enough to work correctly on its return type?

Consider for example `Just :: a -> Maybe a`;  I can write

```
Just . Just . Just ...
```

as many times as I want. Is there a way to write this shortly with something like

```
iterate' 3 Just :: a -> Maybe (Maybe (Maybe a))
```

or do we need something like dependent types to do this?

Comment: You can do this with *template Haskell*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem do you maybe have a link to something similar to what I'm asking

Comment: You might be looking for Free Monads, although it is not precisely what you described.

Comment: Well unfortunately, template Haskell is rather complicated. It is Haskell that writes Haskell syntax so to speak. So you can "generate" a specific `iterate' :: Int -> Name -> Exp` function, and then `iterate'` will "*generate*", Haskell code for that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible with a minor tweak to the syntax you proposed: `iterate' @3 Just` instead of `iterate' 3 Just`.

This is because the result type depends on the number, so the number has to be a *type literal*, not a *value literal*. As you correctly note, doing this with arbitrary numbers would require dependent types[1], which Haskell doesn't have.

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, KindSignatures, DataKinds,
    FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, ScopedTypeVariables,
    FunctionalDependencies, TypeApplications, RankNTypes, FlexibleContexts,
    AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

import qualified GHC.TypeLits as Lit

-- from type-natural
import Data.Type.Natural
import Data.Type.Natural.Builtin

class Iterate (n :: Nat) (f :: * -> *) (a :: *) (r :: *)
  | n f a -> r
  where
  iterate_peano :: Sing n -> (forall b . b -> f b) -> a -> r

instance Iterate 'Z f a a where
  iterate_peano SZ _ = id
instance Iterate n f (f a) r => Iterate ('S n) f a r where
  iterate_peano (SS n) f x = iterate_peano n f (f x)

iterate'
  :: forall (n :: Lit.Nat) f a r .
     (Iterate (ToPeano n) f a r, SingI n)
  => (forall b . b -> f b) -> a -> r
iterate' f a = iterate_peano (sToPeano (sing :: Sing n)) f a
```

If you load this in ghci, you can say

```
*Main> :t iterate' @3 Just
iterate' @3 Just :: a -> Maybe (Maybe (Maybe a))
*Main> iterate' @3 Just True
Just (Just (Just True))
```

This code uses two different type-level naturals: the built-in `Nat` from `GHC.TypeLits` and the classic Peano numerals from `Data.Type.Natural`. The former are needed to provide the nice `iterate' @3` syntax, the latter are needed to perform the recursion (which happens in the `Iterate` class). I used `Data.Type.Natural.Builtin` to convert from a literal to the corresponding Peano numeral.

[1] However, given a specific way to consume the iterated values (e.g. if you know in advance that you'll only want to `show` them), you probably could adapt this code to work even for dynamic values of `n`. There's nothing in the type of `iterate'` that requires a statically known `Nat`; the only challenge is to prove that the result of the iteration satisfies the constraints you need.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with template haskell, if you know the number at compile time (but unless the number is pretty large I don't think it's worth the hassle).  If you don't know the number yet at compile time, you need to correctly model the return type, which we can do using a non-regular type:

```
data Iter f a = Iter0 a | IterS (Iter f (f a))

iterate' :: Int -> (forall x. x -> f x) -> a -> Iter f a
iterate' 0 f x = Iter0 x
iterate' n f x = IterS (iterate' (n-1) f (f x))
```

`Iter` is essentially a way of expressing the data type `a | f a | f (f a) | f (f (f a)) | ...`.  To use the result you need to recurse on `Iter`.  Also the function has to be of the form `a -> f a` for some type constructor `f`, so you may need to do some newtype wrapping to get there.  So... it's kind of a pain either way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without Template Haskell or type-level Nats. The kind of variable-depth recursive type you are building actually fits perfectly into the model of a free monad. We can use the [`unfold`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html#v:unfold) function from the [`free`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free) package to build up a `Free` structure and short-circuit when our counter reaches `0`.

```
-- This extension is enabled so we can have nice type annotations
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad.Free (Free)
import qualified Control.Monad.Free as Free

iterate' :: forall f a. Functor f => Int -> (a -> f a) -> a -> Free f a
iterate' counter0 f x0 = Free.unfold run (counter0, x0)
  where

    -- If counter is 0, short circuit with current result
    -- Otherwise, continue computation with modified counter
    run :: (Int, a) -> Either a (f (Int, a))
    run (0      , x) = Left x
    run (counter, x) = Right (countDown counter <$> f x)

    countDown :: Int -> a -> (Int, a)
    countDown counter x = (counter - 1, x)
```

---

Now, it's easy to create and digest these types of values for any Functor.

```
> iterate' 3 Just True
Free (Just (Free (Just (Free (Just (Pure True))))))

> let f i = if i == 1 then Left "abort" else Right (i+1)

> iterate' 0 f 0
Pure 0
> iterate' 1 f 0
Free (Right (Pure 1))
> iterate' 2 f 0
Free (Right (Free (Left "abort")))
```

---

If your Functor also happens to be a Monad, you can use [`retract`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html#v:retract) to collapse the recursive structure.

```
> Free.retract (iterate' 3 Just True)
Just True
> Free.retract (iterate' 0 f 0)
Right 0
> Free.retract (iterate' 1 f 0)
Right 1
> Free.retract (iterate' 2 f 0)
Left "abort"
```

---

I suggest reading the docs for `Control.Monad.Free` so you can get an idea for how these structures are created/consumed.

---

(Just as an aside, `a -> Maybe a` *is* an endomorphism, but it's an endomorphism in the Kleisli category of Maybe.)